# PayPal IPN: differentiating successful payment response from unsuccessful

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm painfully trying to get going with PayPal's IPN system. Via the Sandbox, I've got it processind payments and sending notifications to my IPN listener.

**Question: what in the response denotes that the payment was succesful?** `verify_sign` looks promising, but then `payer_status` says unverified, which is less so. What would this look like if paymeny had failed?

Example response on success (truncated for brevity):

```
{
    "txn_type": "subscr_signup",
    "subscr_id": "I-X5CCUV52M245",
    "option_selection1": "Some Product",
    "residence_country": "GB",
    "mc_currency": "GBP",
    "item_name": "My Project",
    "recurring": "1",
    "verify_sign": "AxQ2151HawsltpX50Ic0ERjMvTm2AKxR9ZhaRWhY2vsawH.ST73m1oWR",
    "payer_status": "unverified",
    "test_ipn": "1",
    "payer_email": "xxx@xxx.xxx",
    "payer_id": "88F6NGLATYQ3S",
    "option_name1": "Subscription options",
    "reattempt": "1",
    "item_number": "1",
    "subscr_date": "11:23:05 May 24, 2016 PDT",
    "period1": "2 D",
    "mc_amount1": "0.00",
    "period3": "1 Y",
    "mc_amount3": "10.00",
    "ipn_track_id": "1d86661393869"
}
```

I'm unsure how to mimick a failed payment (e.g. legitimate card details but not enough funds in the account) via the Sandbox (since it's all pretend day) so I don't have anything to compare to.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a payment. It is a signup. All you should do when receiving this message is register the user. You will get another transaction for the payment. Until you do, don't give the new user the permissions concerned, or the product, or whatever it is you're selling.

Note that you can get the payment before or after the signup.

Comment: Thanks. So if it *were* a payment, presumably `txn_type` would be something like "payment" (just a guess) - but what in the JSON would denote it had succeeded rather than failed? I'm just trying to get a handle on interpreting these responses, as I can't seem to find a guide that explains them.

Comment: 1. It isn't JSON, it is a set of POST variables. 2. The transaction type is `subscr_payment` in this case. If this arrives, you have the money in your account. Of course it can be reversed out again ... 3. Payment failures are type `subscr_failed`.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, yes, of course it's post - I was thinking JSON as I was echo'ing it out as JSON. You're not aware of a reference for these messages, are you? I can't seem to find one. I need to know what `txn_type` will be for a canceled subscription. Continued thanks.

Comment: Correct: found - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/. Thanks.